# Setting a width to the image before drawImage()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to draw an image on to the canvas element. Regardless of the original image width, how do I set the draw image width to 150px?

```
var cx = $('#canvas').get(0);
var contex= cx.getContext('2d');
var myImg = $('#image').get(0);
contex.drawImage(myImg,215,215);
```

Comment: context.drawImage(img,x,y,width,height);

Comment: That's incredible the things we can find just by reading the docs...

Answer (score 0):

As **SSA** suggested this is the answer. If this may help someone:

```
var cx = $('#canvas').get(0);
var contex= cx.getContext('2d');
var myImg = $('#image').get(0);
contex.drawImage(myImg,215,215,150,150);
```